# getTime() is not a function

Tags: angular, ionic4

```
  time = new Date();
  timeEntered1 = new Date();

  getTime() {
    console.log(this.timeEntered1);
    console.log(this.time);
    console.log(this.timeEntered1.getTime());
    console.log(this.time.getTime());
  }
```

for `console.log(this.time.getTime());` I got an error which "is TypeError: this.timeEntered1.getTime is not a function".

time is a simple `Date()` variable and `timeEntered1` is a `Date()` which the user enter in my html code, and I got it using two way binding. So I do not get why I can use `.getTime` with time and why I can not with `timeEntered1` since they are both a `Date()`.

Here is my html code

```
  <ion-content padding>
    <ion-datetime  
    displayFormat="HH:mm" 
    [(ngModel)]='timeEntered1' 
    picker-format="HH:mm" 
    >
    Choose time: </ion-datetime>
      <ion-button (click)="getTime()">Pick Time</ion-button>
  </ion-content>
```

Comment: So `timeEntered1 instanceof Date` evaluates to true?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: console.log(this.timeEntered1) => What is the output of this?

Comment: datepicker which you are using to enter  `timeEntered1` from html might be giving you a `string` instead of date show your html code here

Comment: 09:47 (the date I picked) @SurjeetBhadauriya

Comment: Um... that's not a date. That's a string that looks like it might represent a time.

Comment: Yeah, it is not a date. The date-picker you are using returning a string instead of date. Try a different date-picker.

Comment: yes.. I think ion-datetime always return a string .. idea to pass through ? @SurjeetBhadauriya

Comment: I updated my code with the html @jitender thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ion-datetime returns the Date as string. So you do not need to instantiate the var time.

You should convert the Datetime string to Date like this.

```
ionDateString = '1968-11-16T00:00:00' 
newDate = new Date(dateString);
```

The ion-datetime is returning the Date in HH:mm format as string, to convert into Date() type try this:

```
getTime() {
let myDate = new Date(Date.prototype.setHours.apply(new Date(), this.timeEntered1.split(':')));

console.log('CONVERTED', myDate);
}
```

Comment: I already tried it, but I got Invalid Date if I console.log your newDate

Comment: now i see... you want only the hours in the Date format right?

try this:
let myDate = new Date(Date.prototype.setHours.apply(new Date(), this.timeEntered1.split(':')));

Comment: Thanks, it works. I still get Property 'split' does not exist on type 'Date'; but it works anyway..

Comment: Just remove the new Date(); from timeEntered1 = new Date();
Type it as string and the error will be gone.

Comment: thanks, now I do not have the error, but I got a Nan value when I console.log ...